# Spivak, Ch. 24, Problem 1a: Does $\sqrt[n]{x}$ converge pointwise to $f(x)=1, x\in (0,1]$, $f(0)=0$ on $(0,1]$ or on $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have a question about pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions.
The question is very specific and simple, and is at the last section below.

Here is my understanding of the concept (based on definition in Spivak's *Calculus*)

Given a function $f(x)$, if we can say that $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ for each $x$ in an interval $A$ (but not for all of the points simultaneously), that is, we can say that

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \forall x, x\in A \implies [\exists N, \forall
n, n>N\implies |f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon]$$

then we say that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $A$.

Note that there is a stronger concept, that of uniform convergence of the sequence $\{f_n\}$, which occurs when we can say

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N, \forall n, n>N \implies [\forall x\in A \implies |f(x)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon]$$

This essentially means that by choosing $N$ large enough, the graph of the function $f_n$ with $n>N$ is arbitrarily close to the graph of $f$ at all points in an interval at the same time.

Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}=\{\sqrt[n]{x}\}$.

A graphical depiction of this sequence of functions, and also of the sequence of numbers $\{f_n(x_1)\}$ is shown below
[image]

Let $$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x\in (0,1] \\ 0, x=0 \end{cases}$$

**The question**

Let $x \in (0,1]$.

$$\sqrt[n]{x}>1-\epsilon \implies \frac{1}{n}\log{x}>\log{(1-\epsilon)}$$

$$\implies n>\frac{\log{x}}{\log{1-\epsilon}}$$

That is, for any $x \in (0,1]$, $\exists N, \forall n, n>N\implies |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$.

Therefore we say that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $(0,1]$.

I just want to make sure of the following: we can't say that it is pointwise  convergent on $[0,1]$, right?

Comment: This sequence is pointwise convergent on $[0,1]$.  Your argument covers the case $x \in (0,1]$, so you will need an additional argument for $x=0$.

Comment: Right, now I see that this is so simple. $f_n(0)=f(0)=0$, so of course the condition of pointwise convergence is always met at $0$.

Comment: I don't think it does. Evianpring already proved that. (S)he only asked how to interpret it (cf. title and end of the post).

Comment: The sequence $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ does converge pointwise in $[0,1]$; the limit is $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{(0,1]}(x)$, that is $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $1$ otherwise (notice $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$). Convergence is not uniform however: $\|f_n-f\|_u=\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f(x)-f_n(x)|=1\not\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$